# how to hide table row when data is empty..?

Tags: php, html

This is my full codes of HTML PHP table page ..

What I'm having trouble with is if a column and row (field) is empty,

I want to hide column and row fields when is data empty.

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>Subjects</td>
      <td>Grades</td>
    </tr>

<?php
    $i=0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results_teach)) {
?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["Sub_1"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Sub_Grades_1"]; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><?php echo $row["Sub_2"]; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row["Sub_Grades_2"]; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
    $i++;
    }
?>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per me, your code will look like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
      <td>Subjects</td>
      <td>Grades</td>
    </tr>

<?php
    $i=0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results_teach)) {
    
      if($row["Sub_1"] != "" && $row["Sub_Grades_1"] != "") { 
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["Sub_1"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["Sub_Grades_1"]; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
      }
    $i++;
    }
?>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Note : Here "Sub_1" & "Sub_Grades_1" will be incremental dynamic value, which comes from database.

Comment: also how to hide full Table,  when "Sub_1" & "Sub_Grades_1" is empty ?

Comment: You can write some dynamic CSS class in else part and once u get blank data set to display:none to hide the whole table.